# не выгружаются фото вариантов

Tags: интеграция, moysklad-pos-api

шлю запрос ассортимента и вариантов (https://online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/entity/assortment/)
фотки товара есть, а вот фотки вариантов не выгружаются.
Пробовал опрашивать карточку варианта.
Выдает ошибку: "Чтение объектов типа 'variant' не поддерживается"
скажите как мне выгрузить через api фотки вариантов?

Answer (score 1):

В [документации по pos api](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/posap/1.0/doc/index.html#pos_data-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8B-%D0%B8-%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8) описан список полей Модификации, который выдается при запросе Ассортимента. В [remap api 1.1](https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/#%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) также указан список полей, который выдается при запросе Модификации в составе Ассортимента. К сожалению пока нет возможности получить Изображения Модификаций через pos api или remap api 1.1.

Answer (score 0):

Тоже сегодня задал вопрос по множественной выгрузке фотографии: [Выгрузка второстепенных фотографий в карточку товара в Интернет-магазине на платформе NetCat_Доработка АПИ со стороны МойСклад](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/962897/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82)

МойСклад планировали в начале марта дописать АПИ.