# Выгрузка второстепенных фотографий в карточку товара в Интернет-магазине на платформе NetCat_Доработка АПИ со стороны МойСклад

Tags: netcat, moysklad-json-api

Дописали модуль по выгрузке 1 фото в карточку товара в Интернет магазин, чтобы выгружалась. Платформа сайта NetCat.

На том момент не было возможности в АПИ по второстепенным фотографиям.

Сейчас есть ли такая возможность уже?

Comment: плюсую, очень нужно получать второстепенные фотографии на json api 1.2

Answer (score 1):

На данный момент возможности работы с несколькими картинками нет, но в ближайшее время выйдет версия remap 1.2, в которой будет данная возможность.

Comment: Уже появилась данная возможность?

Comment: да, можете пользоваться json api 1.2 (но только официального релиза не было еще)